# Unable to boot Win8 after Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, windows-8, boot-repair

After installing Ubuntu I am unable to start Windows 8. The bootsummary is on PasteBin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6145218/

What could be the solution to fix these errors?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 8 DVD, just boot from DVD and select repair option. This will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I did't received a DVD with my laptop. Is possible to create one?

Comment: Yes, you can download it from Microsoft website http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/default.aspx and try to repair. Don't install it again.

Comment: You may not need to download a recovery DVD... most OEM laptops and desktops have a "Recovery partition" on the hard disk in lieu of supplying a physical DVD. (Too bad if your hard disk dies.) When booting your laptop you should see a message along the lines of "Press <Fn> to enter recovery mode" appear briefly, just before the Grub boot loader displays it's message, where <Fn> is one of the function keys across the top of your keyboard.

Comment: Repairing won't harm my Ubuntu system?

Comment: No. It will not harm ubuntu.